# Entity Framework user update

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I get this error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: "Cannot access a disposed object.
>   ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name "

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async void ResetAddress(string userEmail, string address)
{
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userEmail);
        user.Address = address;
        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
}
```

I get the data correctly, and the user reads correctly, what is the cause of the error?

```
await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

Comment: add code for `_userManager.FindByEmailAsync` and `_userManager.UpdateAsync` and note on which line exception occurs

Comment: so which line throws an exception? await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);?

Comment: can you show your code for the startup class where the services are injected